# Calculations Not working properly

Tags: c

I am learning C from a book called "C by Example"

At the end of each chapter there is an exercise to complete. As you can see from the code below, *the exercise is written at the top*

```
/* Chapter 7 Review Exercises #2
- You are a college professor and you have to get the average grades for 10 students. Write a program which prompts you for 10 different grades and then
displays their average */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, score9, score10;

    float average = score1+score2+score3+score4+score5+score6+score7+score8+score9+score10/10;

    printf("Please input the scores of the students: \n");
    scanf(" %f",&score1);
    scanf(" %f",&score2);
    scanf(" %f",&score3);
    scanf(" %f",&score4);
    scanf(" %f",&score5);
    scanf(" %f",&score6);
    scanf(" %f",&score7);
    scanf(" %f",&score8);
    scanf(" %f",&score9);
    scanf(" %f",&score10);

    printf("The average score is: %.2f" , average);

    return 0;

}
```

The problem here is that every time I input numbers (when running the code) It always gives me a HUGE number back (like at least 20 numbers long)

**Is there a way to limit the number, or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve]? It would be easier to answer if we knew your input.

Comment: You need to calculate the `average` **after** inputting its component values...... Or make `average` into a function that would always re-read them on demand. As is, your program invokes undefined behaviour by reading (10) uninitialised variable(s) and storing that in `average`, which is not changed when any of the `score`s are.

Comment: I gave you an answer with corrected code. Please feel free to use it. It got upvoted twice and downvoted twice by other answerers to promote their answers :/ It's a good practice to mark the correct answer as solution with the green tick and upvote correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will work. Your code doesn't work because you try to calculate numbers before they are scanned. Still you have to remember that C keeps order of the operations so `/` is executed before `+`. Add missing brackets `()`. In C the code is processed from top to the bottom!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    float score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7, score8, score9, score10;

    printf("Please input the scores of the students: \n");
    scanf(" %f",&score1);
    scanf(" %f",&score2);
    scanf(" %f",&score3);
    scanf(" %f",&score4);
    scanf(" %f",&score5);
    scanf(" %f",&score6);
    scanf(" %f",&score7);
    scanf(" %f",&score8);
    scanf(" %f",&score9);
    scanf(" %f",&score10);

    float average = (score1+score2+score3+score4+score5+score6+score7+score8+score9+score10)/10;
    printf("The average score is: %.2f" , average);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: OK the answer works, and this isn't a comment against xenteros, but it isn't a very efficient way of doing it.  Try using a loop, although you might not of learnt about them yet.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some parentheses here:

```
float average = score1+score2+score3+score4+score5+score6+score7+score8+score9+score10/10;
```

Change this to:

```
float average = (score1+score2+score3+score4+score5+score6+score7+score8+score9+score10)/10;
```

You also need to move this line down so that it comes *after* the input stage (i.e. after all the calls to `scanf`), since it makes no sense to try and calculate something *before* you have all the input values.

---

You might want to read up on operator precedence, and also loops, since your program can be written much more simply and concisely:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    float average;
    int i;

    printf("Please input the scores of the students: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        float score;

        scanf(" %f", &score);
        sum += score;
    }

    average = sum / n;

    printf("The average score is: %.2f" , average);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know you had to do that! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

The number is indeed wrong, because you don't understand how C executes code. It works top to botom. So if you need the value of score1...score 10, you *first* need to do `scanf` and only then use `+`.

Comment: Ahh that fixed it! Thank you very much for the help! Totally forgot about the top to bottom reading of C :)